Does this sentence lack a second subject: "This figure rose to 50% in 1991, but fell again by 5% in 2001"?

This figure rose to 50% in 1991, but fell again by 5% in 2001.

I've read this sentence online from a native speaker and think that the writer should have either added a subject to the second clause, e.g. it, or removed the comma. Am I right?
I ran into this kind of sentence once and was so sure that it was wrong until I asked a speaker who was definitely more skilled than me, and he said it was a matter of style.

If I read this, I would be uneasy because of 'rose to 50%' followed by 'fell again by 5%'. This would seem potentially ambiguous. Presumably it rose to 50 per cent of something; did it then fall back down to 45%? or to something I need a calculator for? Many native speakers are not very numerate, and I would be unsure what they meant.

in your example, it is evident that it includes a compound predicate.
We insert a comma between the two of them if the two elements could stand alone—if they are independent. That means it would be better if it would be, "This figure rose to 50% in 1991, but it fell again by 5% in 2001." But since the two elements can't stand alone there shouldn't be a comma in between.
Here are some examples:
A. Without a comma:

David likes beef and loves pork.
John loves beef but hates pork.
Joana likes cats and loves dogs.
Marie loves dogs but hates cats.

B. With a comma:

David likes beef, and he loves pork.
John loves beef, but he hates pork.
Joana likes cats, and she loves dogs.
Marie loves dogs, but she hates cats.

